# Can you load modules with wasm files into create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, webassembly

I’m trying to load this module into a create-react-app project: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wasmlibfp

When I do I get the following error:

```
./node_modules/wasmlibfp/wasmlibfp_bg.wasm
Module parse failed: magic header not detected
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: magic header not detected
```

Is there anything special I need to do to load wasm modules in CRA?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can load modules with wasm files into a create-react-app project.  To do this, you will need to make some modifications to the CRA project.  The following steps come from the [Using WebAssembly with React tutorial](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/using-webassembly-with-react) by Richard Reedy:

## Create the CRA:

```
npx create-react-app react-wasm-migration
```

## Install `react-app-rewired` and `wasm-loader` dependencies:

```
npm install react-app-rewired wasm-loader -D
```

## Add a `config-overrides.js` file with the following content:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  const wasmExtensionRegExp = /\.wasm$/;

  config.resolve.extensions.push('.wasm');

  config.module.rules.forEach(rule => {
    (rule.oneOf || []).forEach(oneOf => {
      if (oneOf.loader && oneOf.loader.indexOf('file-loader') >= 0) {
        // make file-loader ignore WASM files
        oneOf.exclude.push(wasmExtensionRegExp);
      }
    });
  });

  // add a dedicated loader for WASM
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: wasmExtensionRegExp,
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    use: [{ loader: require.resolve('wasm-loader'), options: {} }]
  });

  return config;
};
```

## Change the CRA NPM Scripts to use `react-app-rewired` instead of `react-scripts`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-app-rewired start",
  "build": "react-app-rewired build",
  "test": "react-app-rewired test"
}
```

## Install your wasm dependency:

```
npm install --save wasmlibfp
```

## Asynchronously load the WASM in your JS code:

[WebAssembly must be loaded asynchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Loading_and_running), so you will need to add JS code that loads it (I put this in `App.js`):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.loadWasm();
}

loadWasm = async () => {
  try {
    const wasm = await import('external');
    this.setState({wasm});
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(`Unexpected error in loadWasm. [Message: ${err.message}]`);
  }
};
```

## Utilize the wasm code in the app if it has been loaded:

```
render() {
  const { wasm = {} } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      { wasm.doStuff && wasm.doStuff() }
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate you can try just create a normal react app then try to install the dependency.

```
npm install --save wasmlibfp
```