# How to export wasm from an npm package in a way that react.js would be able to use it without plugins?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webassembly, rollup

By default, webpack links your `js` files from your node modules in order to serve them to your client in react. It does not, however, copy over over assets such as `wasm` files. Here is a minimal simple npm package that contains a wasm file.

```
// rollup.config.js
import { wasm } from '@rollup/plugin-wasm';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist/my-library.js',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  plugins: [wasm()]
};
```

```
// src/index.js
import wasm from './example.wasm';

export default loadWasm = () => {
  wasm().then(({ instance }) => {
    // use instance
  });
}
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A description of my library.",
  "main": "dist/my-library.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^2.59.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-wasm": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

For `src./example.wasm` literally any wasm will do.

Then, from any react app, install this npm package and attempt to use it. It will attempt to fetch the wasm resource and fail because it cannot serve the wasm file because webpack didnt copy it.

Here's a sample `App.js` of a react app created with `npx create-react-app my-app`

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import loadWasm from 'my-library';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    loadWasm();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now, I know that `copy-webpack-plugin` can copy the files to the `public` folder but it really isnt ideal imo:

```
webpack: (config) => {
    config.plugins.push(
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          {
            from: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/@xxnetwork/xxdk-npm/dist'),
            to: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
          },
        ],
      }),
    );

    return config;
  }
```

Is there any way that I can serve this npm package including the wasm to users without having them to install additional plugins?

Comment: Maybe the WebAssembly options from here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/experiments/ help. I will try to write a better answer when I have some time. Can you tell me the versions of each software involved in this? Especially webpack, react and npm.

Comment: We actually moved away from webpack because the experiments.asyncWebAssembly = true has no support for the golang glue import object. They have an open ticket for that since 2021. :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you load modules with wasm files into create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259904/can-you-load-modules-with-wasm-files-into-create-react-app)