# How to use onnxruntime-web with React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, onnx, onnxruntime

I am very new to web development, and I'm still learning about the ecosystem, webpack, etc, so forgive me if this question is elementary.

I am trying to integrate onnxruntime-web with a React app, to be able to run inference for some ML models in the browser. However, I am stuck at the very beginning, with an error I am unable to diagnose/solve.

I created by react app with create-react-app. I then run `npm install onnxruntime-web`. After deleting the files from the react project which are not relevant for the minimal example (`App.css`, `logo.svg` and so on) , I am left with App.js in which I have the following code :

```
import * as ort from 'onnxruntime-web';

function App() {
  async function loadModel() {
    const session = await ort.InferenceSession.create('./model.onnx');
  }
  loadModel();
  return (
    <div className="ModelCanvas">
      Here, do stuff with the onnx model
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And a `index.js` :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Now, this gives me the following error when running npm start and going to the app's webpage :

```
ERROR
no available backend found. ERR: [wasm] RuntimeError: Aborted(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info., [cpu] Error: previous call to 'initializeWebAssembly()' failed., [xnnpack] Error: previous call to 'initializeWebAssembly()' failed.
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:7183:23
    at async d.create (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:7162:19)
    at async loadModel (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:26:21)
```

My (not very educated) guess is that is has to do with the webpack configuration automatically generated with create-react-app, but I'm not certain. The strange this, is if I remove the `ort.InferenceSession.create('./model.onnx')`, with something else using the package, say `ort.Tensor = something`, then it works fine, so I guess the `ort` imports works ok.

Of course, `index.js`, `App.js` are all in the same directory, `src`. I put `model.onnx` both in the public folder and in `src`, just in case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you load modules with wasm files into create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259904/can-you-load-modules-with-wasm-files-into-create-react-app)

Comment: I have already tried some react-app-rewired shenanigans, but I will take a look again and try what is written there. I'm not sure how to translate it to my case though, should I replace 'wasmlibfp' with 'onxxruntime-web' ?

Comment: correct, the salient points is you need to use react-rewired and wasm-loader to load your WASM dependency.  Create React App does not support it out of the box.  There may be other alternatives to wasm-loader...

Comment: I haven't gotten around to doing that yet (mostly because I tried it before, without success, but likely because I didn't know what I was doing).

However, I managed to get it to work in the following way :
-Go to node_modules/onnnxruntime-web/dist/
-Take all the files ending in '.wasm', and copy them to public/static/js

This works... Could you confirm to me that doing the stuff with react-app-rewired should automatically includes these files in the build ? Or it should do something else entirely ?